# Calorie Meter refresh input

Tags: vue.js

I am creating Vue.Js calorie counter application, how can I reset values in my input fields after I add the new item?

```
app.foodItems.push({
                    name: app.newFoodItems[0].name,
                    calories: app.newFoodItems[0].calories,
                    protein: app.newFoodItems[0].protein,
                    fats: app.newFoodItems[0].fats,
                    carbs: app.newFoodItems[0].carbs,
                });
```

When i add the new item I want to refresh the input field so user can input the new Item from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like the following inside your `app.foodItems.push`

```
                app.newFoodItems[0].name = '';
                app.newFoodItems[0].calories = '';
                app.newFoodItems[0].protein = '';
                app.newFoodItems[0].fats = '';
                app.newFoodItems[0].carbs = '';
```